# Python: get unknown word in a string using regex, using its boundaries

Tags: python, regex, string

I Have the following string

```
string1 = '    name.somefunction() '
```

I want to get only the part of string1: 'name'. BUT 'name' is not always the same, in different strings in my problem.
So I need to use regex to match a word that is between any whitespace and the string: '.somefunction()', but I don't really know to write the regex properly.
Any help would be more than welcome

Comment: Have you looked at some regexp examples online? Some docs, tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lookahead operator. This expression should match any word before the `.` character:

```
\w*(?=\.)
```

Here is an example of this in python:

```
# IMPORT
import re

# INPUT STRING
inputString = '    name.somefunction() '

# GET LIST OF MATCHES FROM EXPRESSION 
matches = re.findall('\w*(?=\.)', inputString)

# PRINT FIRST MATCH
print(matches[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
regex = re.compile(r'\s+(\w+)\.somefunction\(\)')
match = re.search(regex, string1)
word = match.group(1)
```

The variable 'word' will get the value within the parentheses `(\w+)`, which in this case is 'name'.

To explain, `\s+` matches one or more consecutive whitespace characters (spaces, in this case, though it could be any other whitespace). `(\w+)` constitutes a matching group (the match object saves anything matched within parentheses) containing 1 or more word characters (letters, numbers, underscore). The `\.` is a literal `.` character, and then `somefunction()` is there to make sure you are only matching cases of the specific function you want.

If you want to make the expression more specific to what is a valid python variable name, change the regex to `r'\s+([a-zA-Z_]\w*)\.somefunction()`.

Comment: This will return more than just `name`, and the `()` are special regex symbols that will need to be escaped

Comment: I don't think you understand the purpose of `word = match.group(1)`

Comment: @Tony good catch on the parentheses, though, I did make that edit

Comment: Ya sorry I missed that `match.group(1)` bit